# Alignment of items in poster

Tags: itemize, captionof

within an itemize environment I have the following problem: After inserting two pictures followed by a caption using *captionof*, the first item after the pictures is not aligned with the items before the picture anymore. When removing the *captionof* command, there's no problem.
Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
 \item blablabla.

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{figures/hirf_aircraft.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\captionof{figure}{blablabla}

\item blablabla
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Place the `\captionof` into the minipage together with the images (I also changed the width of the image to `\linewidth` to make sure the caption is centred with respect to the image):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
 \item blablabla.

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\captionof{figure}{blablabla}
\end{minipage}


\item blablabla
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]